# Monthly Price data: Open, High, Low and Close

Tags: sqlite

I have a table that is built up as follows:

```
dpTicker    dpDate      dpOpen      dpHigh      dpLow       dpClose     dpVolume    dpAdjClose  dpCreated            dpModified
GLE.PA      2016-02-01  35.39       35.455      34.375      34.785      2951300     34.785      2016-02-06 13:33:40  2016-02-06 13:33:40
GLE.PA      2016-02-02  34.515      34.565      32.165      32.575      7353600     32.575      2016-02-06 13:33:40  2016-02-06 13:33:40
GLE.PA      2016-02-03  32.4        32.495      30.885      31.6        7007000     31.6        2016-02-06 13:33:40  2016-02-06 13:33:40
GLE.PA      2016-02-04  32.075      32.38       30.67       31.98       8181000     31.98       2016-02-06 13:33:40  2016-02-06 13:33:40
GLE.PA      2016-02-05  32.55       33.0        31.86       32.11       7056700     32.11       2016-02-06 13:33:40  2016-02-06 13:33:40
```

The data is daily share price information and the table contains hundreds of tickers (eg GLE.PA).  Each ticker (eg GLE.PA) has an entry for each "Business Day".

My objective is to query Monthly Price Summaries from this Daily Price data table.   The monthly data is constructed as follows:

1. Month Open: dpOpen at the first business day of the month;
2. Month high: max(dpHigh) of the month;
3. Month Low: min(dpLow) of the month;
4. Month Close: dpClose at the last business date of the month.

I manage to query the data for a specific month by using the following query in SQLite3:

```
SELECT
    strftime ('%Y-%m', dpDate) AS month,    
    (SELECT dpOpen
        FROM DailyPrices
        WHERE dpTicker = 'GLE.PA'
        AND dpDate = 
        (SELECT min(dpDate)
        FROM DailyPrices
        WHERE strftime('%Y%m', dpDate) = '201509'   
        )
    ) AS Open,
    max(dpHigh) AS High,
    min (dpLow) AS Low,
    (SELECT dpClose
        FROM DailyPrices
        WHERE dpTicker = 'GLE.PA'
        AND dpDate = 
        (SELECT max(dpDate)
        FROM DailyPrices
        WHERE strftime('%Y%m', dpDate) = '201509'   
        )
    ) AS Close
FROM DailyPrices
WHERE dpTicker ='GLE.PA'
AND strftime('%Y%m', dpDate) = '201509';
```

The output of the query is as follows:

```
bash-3.2$ sqlite3 myShares < month.sql
month       Open        High        Low         Close     
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
2015-09     42.72       44.07       37.25       39.85     
bash-3.2$
```

With the following query I manage to generate a monthly overview for the High and Low:

```
SELECT  
    strftime('%Y-%m', dpDate) AS Month,
    max(dpHigh) AS High,
    min(dpLow) AS Low
FROM DailyPrices
WHERE dpTicker ='GLE.PA'
GROUP BY strftime('%Y%m', update);
```

A snapshot of the output looks as follows:

```
bash-3.2$ sqlite3 myShares < monthly.sql
Month       High        Low       
----------  ----------  ----------
2000-01     219.32      184.346   
2000-02     206.43      181.977   
2000-03     210.411     181.503   
2000-04     221.405     197.805   
2000-05     226.239     55.9199
...
```

With the following query, I manage to extract the correct Open and by analogy the correct Close data:

```
SELECT 
    strftime('%Y-%m', dpDate) AS Month, 
    dpOpen AS Open
FROM DailyPrices
WHERE dpTicker = 'GLE.PA' 
AND dpDate IN
    (SELECT min(dpDate)
        FROM DailyPrices
        WHERE dpTicker = 'GLE.PA'
        GROUP BY strftime('%Y%m', dpDate)
    );
```

A snapshot of the output is as follows:

```
bash-3.2$ sqlite3 myShares < Open.sql
Month       Open      
----------  ----------
2000-01     218.846   
2000-02     200.269   
2000-03     206.525   
2000-04     201.312   
2000-05     215.908 
...
```

I am struggling to combine the queries, month.sql and open.sql, into one query to obtain the following output:

```
Month    Open    High    Low    Close
-------  -----   -----   -----  -----
2015-01  42.79   42.79   33.69  35.18
2015-02  35.39   35.46   26.61  32.42
2015-03  32.32   37.65   31.93  32.48
...
```

Any help to solving this question would be highly appreciate.
Best Regards

Gam

Comment: So you want the first query, but for all months?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three places where the first query refers to the specific month searched for. Let's remove the two occurences in the subqueries; this requires using aliases so that we can refer to other instances of the same table by name:

```
SELECT
    strftime ('%Y-%m', dpDate) AS month,    
    (SELECT dpOpen
        FROM DailyPrices
        WHERE dpTicker = 'GLE.PA'
        AND dpDate = 
        (SELECT min(dpDate)
        FROM DailyPrices AS DP2
        WHERE strftime('%Y%m', DP2.dpDate) = strftime('%Y%m', DP1.dpDate)
        )
    ) AS Open,
    max(dpHigh) AS High,
    min (dpLow) AS Low,
    (SELECT dpClose
        FROM DailyPrices
        WHERE dpTicker = 'GLE.PA'
        AND dpDate = 
        (SELECT max(dpDate)
        FROM DailyPrices AS DP2
        WHERE strftime('%Y%m', DP2.dpDate) = strftime('%Y%m', DP1.dpDate)
        )
    ) AS Close
FROM DailyPrices AS DP1
WHERE dpTicker ='GLE.PA'
AND strftime('%Y%m', dpDate) = '201509';
```

Now that only the outermost query needs to know the month, we can simply replace the filter with GROUP BY:

```
SELECT
    strftime ('%Y-%m', dpDate) AS month,    
    (...) AS Open,
    max(dpHigh) AS High,
    min (dpLow) AS Low,
    (...) AS Close
FROM DailyPrices
WHERE dpTicker ='GLE.PA'
GROUP BY strftime('%Y%m', dpDate);
```

---

Please note that the open/close subquery can be simplified by using ORDER BY/LIMIT:

```
(SELECT dpOpen
 FROM DailyPrices
 WHERE dpTicker = 'GLE.PA'
   AND ... dpDate ...
 ORDER BY dpDate ASC
 LIMIT 1) AS Open
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks CL!!   This is good learning for a SQLite newbie, especially for the use of ALIASES.

Your suggestions produce generally good results, however, when running a couple of test runs I noticed occasional errors of the following style:

```
bash-3.2$ sqlite3 myShares < tst.sql
month       Open        High        Low         Close     
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
2006-03     75.4675     76.5852     70.4136     74.4956   
2006-04     75.0787     75.9048     70.5108     72.7948   
2006-05                 77.0225     68.5184     70.7538   
2006-06     70.5594     73.4751     64.7767     72.7462   
2006-07     72.5518     75.2245     68.2269     74.0582   
bash-3.2$
```

As you can notice, the Open price for the month of May 2006 is missing.  I verified that the data actually exists:

```
bash-3.2$ sqlite3 myShares < test.sql
dpTicker    dpDate      dpOpen      dpHigh      dpLow       dpClose     dpVolume    dpAdjClose  dpCreated            dpModified         
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  -------------------  -------------------
BNP.PA      2006-04-26  72.0173     73.1835     72.0173     72.892      2623400     48.8861     2015-12-08 12:04:22  2015-12-08 12:04:22
BNP.PA      2006-04-27  73.8153     74.0096     72.5032     73.6209     6001400     49.375      2015-12-08 12:04:22  2015-12-08 12:04:22
BNP.PA      2006-04-28  73.4751     73.9611     72.6976     72.7948     4133300     48.8209     2015-12-08 12:04:22  2015-12-08 12:04:22
BNP.PA      2006-05-02  72.5518     73.5723     72.3574     73.2807     3085400     49.1468     2015-12-08 12:04:22  2015-12-08 12:04:22
BNP.PA      2006-05-03  73.8639     74.0096     72.5518     72.649      3290400     48.7231     2015-12-08 12:04:22  2015-12-08 12:04:22
BNP.PA      2006-05-04  72.892      73.5237     72.2602     73.3779     3640300     49.212      2015-12-08 12:04:22  2015-12-08 12:04:22
BNP.PA      2006-05-05  73.6209     74.8357     73.4751     74.7872     3255600     50.1572     2015-12-08 12:04:22  2015-12-08 12:04:22
bash-3.2$
```

For each of the tickers in the SQLite database, I have typically around 4 of those errors over a 16 year period.

As far as my SQLite newbie knowledge reaches, the data in the table is fine.

Any idea why occasionally, the query jumps a summary record?  Generally, the descrepancy occurs on the Open Price, but from time to time also on the Close price.

Best regards,

GAM

For the record, the following is the query I have executed

```
SELECT
    strftime ('%Y-%m', dpDate) AS month,    
    (SELECT dpOpen
     FROM DailyPrices
     WHERE dpTicker = 'BNP.PA'
       AND dpDate = 
        (SELECT min(dpDate)
        FROM DailyPrices AS DP2
        WHERE strftime('%Y%m', DP2.dpDate) = strftime('%Y%m', DP1.dpDate)
        )
     ORDER BY dpDate ASC
     LIMIT 1) AS Open,
    max(dpHigh) AS High,
    min (dpLow) AS Low,
    (SELECT dpClose
        FROM DailyPrices
        WHERE dpTicker = 'BNP.PA'
        AND dpDate = 
        (SELECT max(dpDate)
        FROM DailyPrices AS DP2
        WHERE strftime('%Y%m', DP2.dpDate) = strftime('%Y%m', DP1.dpDate)
        )
    ) AS Close
FROM DailyPrices AS DP1
WHERE dpTicker ='BNP.PA'
AND strftime('%Y-%m', dpDate) > '2006-02'
AND strftime('%Y-%m', dpDate) < '2006-08'
GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m', dpDate);
```

Comment: Improved the SELECT dpOpen and dpClose:

Comment: (SELECT dpClose
        FROM DailyPrices
        WHERE dpTicker = 'GLE.PA'
        AND dpDate = 
        (SELECT max(dpDate)
        FROM DailyPrices AS DP2
        WHERE dpTicker = 'GLE.PA'
  AND strftime('%Y%m', DP2.dpDate) = strftime('%Y%m', DP1.dpDate)
        )
    ) AS Close